# Do Doubling Rings work on a Gauntlet?

Tags: magic-items, weapons, pathfinder-2e

[Doubling Rings](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=432):

> When you **wield** a melee weapon in the hand wearing the golden ring, the weapon’s fundamental runes are replicated onto any melee weapon you **wield** in the hand wearing the iron ring.

Basicaly the question is, do I *wield* a Gauntlet, or just wear it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Gauntlets](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=4) are Free Hand Weapons. The Free Hand trait says, in part

> When you’re not wielding anything and not otherwise using the hand, you can use abilities that require you to have a hand free **as well as those that require you to be wielding a weapon in that hand**. Each of your hands can have only one free-hand weapon on it.

I would interpret this to mean that, as long as you don't have anything else in the gauntleted hand, then the gauntlet can make use of the doubling ring.